# Displaying radio buttons 2 rows and 3 columns programatically in android

Tags: android, dynamic, radio-button

Here is my code

```
final RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[6];
        RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(this);
        rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);

        for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
            rb[i]  = new RadioButton(this);
            rb[i].setText("Dynamic Radio Button " + i);
            rb[i].setId(i);
            rb[i].getGlobalVisibleRect(null);
             rg.addView(rb[i]); 
          }
           ll.addView(rg);
```

I am trying to display these radio buttons programatically. I got 6 radio buttons but am unable to display these as rows and columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TableLayout to arrange the Radio Button in Rows and Columns

**Sample Code**

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    TableLayout tl = new TableLayout(this);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(this);
        rb.setText("Dynamic Radio Button " + i);
        rb.setId(i);
        rb.getGlobalVisibleRect(null);
        tr.addView(rb);
        }
        tl.addView(tr);
    }
ll.addView(tl);
setContentView(ll);
```

[image: Screenshots]

[Screenshots link](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-Ab-V87VguY8/TzYJGeAWpgE/AAAAAAAAEhA/T4IHdqkimLg/s64-c/Screenshots.jpg)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i need single selection radio buttons